# GROUP BY with multiple columns summing with multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

Hello I am trying to practice using GROUP BY and SUM, When I aggregate using count with just 1 column it works great!

```
SELECT
  [ActivityId]
  ,[Timestamp]
  ,COUNT(*)
  FROM [DATABASE].[db].[Log] AS ACTIVITY
  GROUP BY [ActivityId],[Timestamp]
  ORDER BY [ActivityId] DESC
```

Returns:

```
ActivityId  Timestamp   (No column name)
0AF072B4-B9EB-41B3-8DF6-F9AE66BEC57E    2017-08-04 15:59:30.3592694 1
E522028D-4791-452E-B001-F6A448415DEA    2017-08-04 15:59:26.3501979 1
E522028D-4791-452E-B001-F6A448415DEA    2017-08-04 15:59:54.9596809 1
38E8E5A9-1729-42C4-B055-DE2BB4711738    2017-08-04 15:59:57.2996059 1
```

This does not aggregate the way I want, the activityIds still stay uncounted &
 aggregated (they all show 1)

```
SELECT
  [ActivityId]
  ,COUNT(*)
  FROM [DATABASE].[db].[Log] AS ACTIVITY
  GROUP BY [ActivityId]
  ORDER BY [ActivityId] DESC
```

however the above code works fine! This is the correct aggregation (but with only 1 field):

```
ActivityId  (No column name)
0AF072B4-B9EB-41B3-8DF6-F9AE66BEC57E    1
E522028D-4791-452E-B001-F6A448415DEA    2
38E8E5A9-1729-42C4-B055-DE2BB4711738    2
3306CEB5-F476-432F-BD62-DA328C93D764    2
```

If I don't include the other fields in the group by I get:

```
 "is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."
```

Should I even be using group by? Or do I do a sub-select or something? I want to aggregrate on the activityId field, AND include the other fields like (timestamp or email)

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  You have presented two valid queries.  It is unclear what you want to do.

Comment: Thank you I have added some query results to help clarify

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```
SELECT l.*, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY ActivityId) as Activity_Count
FROM [DATABASE].[db].[Log] l
ORDER BY ActivityId DESC;
```

This adds the count for each activity to each row.

Answer (score 0):

When you include timestamp in the select with a group by columns other than timestamp, the database does not know which row from among the group of timestamps for the given activity you wish to select. That is why it insists on adding an aggregate function around all fields not included in the group-by.

You can find the earliest and the latest timestamps for each activity ID like this:

```
SELECT
  [ActivityId]
, MIN(Timestamp) AS EarliestActivity
, MAX(Timestamp) AS LatestActivity
, COUNT(*) AS ActivityCount
FROM [DATABASE].[db].[Log] AS ACTIVITY
  GROUP BY [ActivityId]
  ORDER BY [ActivityId] DESC
```